# Probability of false negative test

Tags: probability, statistics

I have an assignment that states that the probability of having a disease is $0.11\%$. When Mark takes a test which is $95\%$ accurate, the test is negative.

Then the question is what the probability is that Mark has the disease?

My attempt to solve the assignment: $0.0011\times0.05=0.000055=0.0055\%$.

This seems like a very small number. Are there some numbers I have neglected?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Let $A$ be the event that Mark has the disease, $B$ be the event that Mark gets a negative test. We want to find $P(A|B)$. By definition

$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}=\frac{0.0011 \cdot (1-0.95)}{[0.0011 \cdot (1-0.95)] + [(1-0.0011)\cdot 0.95]}=5.8 \times 10^{-5},$$

as the probability the test comes back negative arises from the two possibilities being he is sick and the test is wrong or he is healthy and the test is correct.

Hope that helps.